# Java Regex Name Validation

Tags: java, regex, string

Please I need help. I am writing a function for validation...
The conditions are : *Name length should be between 2 & 30
*The first letter of each word should be capital(Steve Smith is valid; steve Smith is invalid or Steve smith is invalid)
*There should be space between each words & name shouldn't start or end with space.

```
String regex = "([A-Z][A-Za-z]+ )+{2,30}";
    if(name.matches(regex))
      return true;
    return false;
```

This is the snippet in the function used to validate the name.
Will appreciate the help.
Thank You in advance.

Comment: You've described what your goal is and what you have tried so far - so far so good. However what is missing is a description where exactly you need help or what the problem with your current solution is. I suspect the regular expression you posted does not work as you expect. You should add a description of where your current solution fails (Examples of Strings it wrongly accepts as valid or invalid).

Comment: `S T E V E` would be valid too, according to your definition.

Comment: @maraca also, "Vincent van Gogh" will be invalid.

Comment: "^([A-Z][A-Za-z]+ ) {2,30}     ............ I currently did this and [rogerer federer] is invalid which is correct but [Steve], [St], [Steve Smith] all are showing false

Comment: The above is incomplete . I am learning and modifying the regex string accordingly now.

Comment: The cases which showed false also were false in my original regex string too.

Comment: `"(?=.{2,30}$)\\p{Lu}\\p{L}+(?:\\s\\p{Lu}\\p{L}+)*"`

Comment: Your regular expression seems to require that the name ends in a space.

Answer (score 2):

To extract word starts with uppercase then all lower case - `([A-Z]([a-z]*))`

```
public static boolean isValidIdentifier(String identifier)
{

    // Regex to check valid identifier.
    String regex = "^(?=.{2,20}$)([A-Z]([a-z]*))+(\\s+([A-Z]([a-z]*)))*$";

    // Compile the ReGex
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

    // If the identifier is empty
    // return false
    if (identifier == null) {
        return false;
    }

    // Pattern class contains matcher() method
    // to find matching between given identifier
    // and regular expression.
    Matcher m = p.matcher(identifier);

    // Return if the identifier
    // matched the ReGex
    return m.matches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
([A-Z][A-Za-z]* )+([A-Z][A-Za-z]+)
```

I am assuming you can have name with single word also with first letter in uppercase and all other in lowercase, and there will be only one space between 2 words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```java
String regex = "(?=.{2,30}$)\\p{Lu}\\p{L}+(?:\\s\\p{Lu}\\p{L}+)*";
```

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string (implicit in `matches()`)
- `(?=.{2,30}$)` - a positive lookahead: from 2 till 30 any chars other than line break chars
- `\p{Lu}` - an uppercase letter
- `\p{L}+` - one or more letters
- `(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{L}+)*` - zero or more sequences of an uppercase letter, one or more letters and one or more letters
- `\z` - end of string (implicit in `matches()`).